# How to create CPP project in Sentry on-premise version

Tags: c++, sentry

I want to use Sentry for CPP project, and I found cpp [client crow](https://github.com/nlohmann/crow), but when open `Create a new Project` in Sentry, cannot find anything about cpp for Server or any type.

How can I create a CPP type project in Sentry? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this question. There no exactly match CPP type project, but there have a `minidump` project for a category language.

Answer (score 0):

The project type in Sentry is useful to show you how to configure your application.
Even if you create a project of type JavaScript, it will work with events of any type.

For example, you can have a project (of any type) and send events from your C#/ASP.NET Core or Python/Django project and also from your TypeScript/JavaScript front end.

Comment: yeah. When I first use, I can't find C++ project, after check some doc, find there have Minidump type.